# why can't an element be accessed from the name attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery

what is the main reason  that we cannot access the element from its name attribute rather it can be accessed from id attribute

```
<input type="text" name="textname" id="textid" value="">
<input type="button" name ="buttonname" id ="buttonid" value ="button"

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){
        $("#textname").val ="text1";//doesnot  work 
        $("#textid").val ="text1";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`#` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) selects elements with a matching *ID*, not name.

You can select `<input>` elements names `textname` like this:

```
$('input[name="textname"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) which has **full examples**?

```
$('[name="something"]')
```

for val,

```
$('[name="something"]').val('set to this')
```

It's kind of pointless to reference by name if that element already has a unique ID and you are only targeting it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can using this syntax.

```
$("input[name='mycontrolname']")
```

The reason it isn't the standard way of referencing elements is that the name element of a tag doesn't have to be unique, whereas the ID does.

For example, with radio buttons it is common to code them like so (note the name attributes):

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
 <input type="radio" id="myRadio1" name="myradio" value="1">one
 <input type="radio" id="myRadio2" name="myradio" value="2">two
 <input type="radio" id="myRadio3"name="myradio" value="3">three
</form>
```